# Styles are not applying to views other than home view (asp.net core mvc 5.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net5

I have a problem with the code, the style is only applied to the home page. Although the program adds the page on the _Layout at runtime

view code:

````
    ViewData["about us"] = "Join Us";
}

<style>
    .PG {
        background-color: white;
    }

    * {
        color: #28285c;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    .aaa:hover {
        color: #28285c;
    }```

startup code:
````

app.UseRouting();

````
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });```
````

_ViewStart code:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Comment: Do you have a shared layout?

Comment: Where you add the style? The style should add in the _Layout.csthml page, instead of the Home/Index Page. Besides, if the style is added in the _Layout.cshtml page, in other view page (use the _Layout.cshtml page), whether it contains the relate element with the same class name? Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether you could find the relate elements and the styles?